# How to cut data from one column and paste into a new column in Python -> Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [{'name': 'RealMadrid_RT'}, {'name': 'Bavaria_FD'}, {'name': 'Lion_NS'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

I need to create new column -> df['name_2'], next, cut the data from column df['name'] and paste to column df['name_2']. I require getting the next result how on the screenshot

[image]

I will be grateful for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.extract` to get the expected outcome:

```
# With underscore
>>> df['name'].str.extract('(.*)(_.*)').rename(columns={0: 'name', 1: 'name_2'})
         name name_2
0  RealMadrid    _RT
1     Bavaria    _FD
2        Lion    _NS

# Without underscore
>>> df['name'].str.extract('(.*)_(.*)').rename(columns={0: 'name', 1: 'name_2'})
         name name_2
0  RealMadrid     RT
1     Bavaria     FD
2        Lion     NS
```

Comment: Thanks, extract it is good option and some new solution for me, and your answer working.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the underscore in the second column, this will work:

```py
df = df['name'].str.split('_', expand=True)
df.columns = ['name', 'name2']
```

If you *do* want the underscore in the second column, this will work for that:

```py
df = df['name'].str.split('(?=_)', expand=True)
df.columns = ['name', 'name2']
```

Comment: Good option, I also like it, it works well, thanks